# Do I need to wrap email messages longer than 72 characters in a line?

Tags: email, standards

Occasionally I've seen code wrapping email messages to make sure a single line is no more than 72 characters long. Is there really need for this and what is this all about?

Comment: Good answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696433/is-it-necessary-to-wrap-long-lines-when-sending-emails/2696542#2696542

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expand on Joe's response, the 72-char limit basically allows for bodies to then be quoted, so it gives room for the additional chars added to a line, e.g.,

```
From "scratch":
> From Joe Bloggs, 24 Sept 1985
>
> > Probably some flame about emacs vs vi, eulogising one over the other.
> > The quote chars have added four characters to the start of the line, so
> > forcing wrapped lines at 72 chars pushes this to 76 chars, without
> > affecting the formatting of the paragraph.
> 
> Some rant accusing Joe of talking crap, and throwing out some random
> evidence to the contrary. Quote char adds 2 chars. Again, paragraph
> formatting retained.

Someone else chimes in deciding to eulogise pico over either of the
other two editors. All sides about to turn on this person. :-)
```

So giving an extra few chars allows the parapgraph formatting to be retained on 80-character terminals, for at least two levels, and potentially more depending on how the quote characters are added/used.

Comment: Is this still necessary these days?

Comment: Probably not, as most email readers will wordwrap properly. There's still an issue with quoting older bodies as smart word-wrap can distort the text, making it tricky to see where text has been quoted. Ultimately, to *not* do this breaks the internet's Robustness Principle of "be conservative in what you send". This basically states that if you don't know what the recipient is using to receive/read mail, so don't make assumptions, and play safe. Of course, if you know what the recipient uses, you can make allowances accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

[RFC 2822](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2822.txt) contains this text about line lengths, which is where this likely comes from:

> There are two limits that this
>   standard places on the number of
>   characters in a line. Each line of
>   characters MUST be no more than    998
>   characters, and SHOULD be no more than
>   78 characters, excluding    the CRLF.
>
> The 998 character limit is due to
>   limitations in many implementations
>   which send, receive, or store Internet
>   Message Format messages that    simply
>   cannot handle more than 998 characters
>   on a line. Receiving
>   implementations would do well to
>   handle an arbitrarily large number
>   of characters in a line for robustness
>   sake. However, there are so    many
>   implementations which (in compliance
>   with the transport    requirements of
>   [RFC2821]) do not accept messages
>   containing more    than 1000 character
>   including the CR and LF per line, it
>   is important    for implementations
>   not to create such messages.
>
> The more conservative 78 character
>   recommendation is to accommodate
>   the many implementations of user
>   interfaces that display these
>   messages which may truncate, or
>   disastrously wrap, the display of
>   more than 78 characters per line, in
>   spite of the fact that such
>   implementations are non-conformant to
>   the intent of this    specification
>   (and that of [RFC2821] if they
>   actually cause    information to be
>   lost). Again, even though this
>   limitation is put on    messages, it
>   is encumbant upon implementations
>   which display messages

Comment: Is this still necessary these days?